# From which OpenGL version is the function "glDrawArrays" released?

Tags: opengl

I want to know from which OpenGL version is the function "glDrawArrays" released, i.e., the lowest version of OpenGL that supports this function. It seems that the official website of OpenGL doesn't provide this kind of information. So, could you please answer this question or tell me where I can find it? Thank you.

Comment: OpenGL **1.1** added vertex arrays.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[This OpenGL Wiki page](http://www.opengl.org/wiki/GlDrawArrays) says it's from OpenGL 1.1, which is available basically everywhere nowadays.

Answer (score 4):

Beyond giving you the answer for this example, here is a systematic way to find which versions each entry point is available in, based on official information:

- Go to www.opengl.org.
- Choose "OpenGL Registry" from the "Documentation" drop-down close to the top left corner of the page.
- Scroll down until you see a section "XML API Registry of Reserved Enumerants and Functions".
- Click the "anonymous public access" link in that section.
- Click `gl.xml` in the file list that appears.
- Now search for the entry point you're looking for in the XML file.

Using the example of `glDrawArrays`, you will first find a couple of `<command>` XML tags that define the arguments. Then it shows up again in lists of entry points. If you look for the containing tags of those lists, you find it under:

```
<feature api="gl" name="GL_VERSION_1_1" number="1.1">
    ...
    <command name="glDrawArrays"/>
    ...
<feature api="gles1" name="GL_VERSION_ES_CM_1_0" number="1.0">
    ...
    <command name="glDrawArrays"/>
    ...
<feature api="gles2" name="GL_ES_VERSION_2_0" number="2.0">
    ...
    <command name="glDrawArrays"/>
    ...
```

So there you have it. OpenGL 1.1, OpenGL ES 1.0, and OpenGL ES 2.0. It might seem surprising at first sight that ES 2.0 is listed separately, since the entry point normally carry over to newer versions unless specified otherwise. But ES 2.0 was defined as a new API, not as a new version of ES 1.0.

Comment: Thank you very much. This is the most official answer one can get.